# Perl code, I don't understand the error outputted

Tags: perl

```
#!perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Net::SMTP;

my $smtpserver = 'server';
my $smtpport = 25;
my $smtpuser   = 'username';
my $smtppassword = 'password';

my $smtp = Net::SMTP->new($smtpserver, Port=>$smtpport, Timeout => 10, Debug => 1);
die "Could not connect to server!\n" unless $smtp;

$smtp->auth($smtpuser, $smtppassword);
$smtp->mail('sender@example.com');
$smtp->to('mymail@gmail.com');
$smtp->data();
$smtp->datasend("To: mymail\@gmail.com\n");
$smtp->datasend("bla bla bla ... \n");
$smtp->quit;
```

When I execute this code I got the below output. I don't have much more knowledge about perl but the project is Perl, thus I must do it this way.

What is happening below: I do not understand it personally.

```
    Net::SMTP>>> Net::SMTP(2.29)
    Net::SMTP>>>   Net::Cmd(2.26)
    Net::SMTP>>>     Exporter(5.58)enter code here
    Net::SMTP>>>   IO::Socket::INET(1.27)
    Net::SMTP>>>     IO::Socket(1.28)
    Net::SMTP>>>       IO::Handle(1.24)
    Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x7a6280)<<< 220 server ESMTP Sendmail 8.13.1/8.13.1; Sun, 6 Dec 2015 19:34:41 +0530
    Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x7a6280)>>> EHLO localhost.localdomain
    Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x7a6280)<<< 250-server Hello localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1], pleased to meet you
    Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x7a6280)<<< 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
    Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x7a6280)<<< 250-PIPELINING
    Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x7a6280)<<< 250-8BITMIME
    Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x7a6280)<<< 250-SIZE
    Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x7a6280)<<< 250-DSN
    Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x7a6280)<<< 250-ETRN
    Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x7a6280)<<< 250-AUTH GSSAPI DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5
    Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x7a6280)<<< 250-DELIVERBY
    Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x7a6280)<<< 250 HELP
    Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x7a6280)>>> MAIL FROM:<sendermail>
    Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x7a6280)<<< 250 2.1.0 <sendermail>... Sender ok
    Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x7a6280)>>> RCPT TO:<receipient mail>
    Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x7a6280)<<< 250 2.1.5 <recipient mail>... Recipient ok
    Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x7a6280)>>> DATA
    Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x7a6280)<<< 354 Enter mail, end with "." on a line by itself
    Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x7a6280)>>> To: mymail@gmail.com
    Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x7a6280)>>> .
    Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x7a6280)<<< 250 2.0.0 tB6EJbum025820 Message accepted for delivery
    Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x7a6280)>>> QUIT
    Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x7a6280)<<< 221 2.0.0 server closing connection
```

I will be very grateful for any help — thanks in advance.

Comment: What makes you think it's not working?

Comment: It says it sent the mail to mymail@gmail.com, are you saying you didn't receive an email? Put the to email address to a real account.

Comment: I have send the mail to a real email account.But i didn't receive any mail in my account.

Comment: Can you send email from the system using something like sendmail? Is the MTA working locally? Have you tested sending to another email domain, i.e. not Gmail as that may not trust the sender.

Comment: yes i have tried many times in my domain but i didn't get email and also i sent email to hotmail but it didn't work .

Comment: Have you tried looking in your SMTP server logs? You have an ID (`tB6EJbum025820`), you should be able to tell from your server logs where it went.

Comment: when i check that the smtp port is on or not by zenmap it tells me that port is not open ,i want to ask that is it work or not in that situation?

Answer (score 3):

> *I don't understand the error outputted*

You didn't show us any error. As you can see, the server said "Message accepted for delivery".

The missing `->dataend` might mean you are sending an empty email, though.

> *What is happening below*

An email message is being sent. As well, messages to help you debug problems are being outputted since you requested these using `Debug => 1`.